# How to set header in magento2 controller function?

Tags: magento2, header

I am trying to create a ICS file, core php I wrote the code like this -

```
    include 'ICS.php';

header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');

$ics = new ICS(array(
  'location' => '123 test St, New York, NY  ',
  'description' => 'This is my description',
  'dtstart' => '2018-8-16 9:00AM',
  'dtend' => '2018-8-16 10:00AM',
  'summary' => 'Testing',
  'url' => 'www.google.com'
));

file_put_contents('/home/test.ics', $ics->to_string());
```

Its running fine.

Now I am trying to implement the code in Magento2 controller's private function. But how can I set `header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');` in magento2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set like this :

```
$this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','text/calendar',true);
```

It maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

...

private $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    ...
    $this->pageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

...
...

$page = $this->pageFactory->create();

$page->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);

return $page;
```